# How to customize Ionic Datetime?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ionic-framework, ionic2

Is there any way to change the styling of this component?
And not only some basic stuff like colour and size but the entire style, buttons, etc.

Comment: You are not talking about the scss variables, are you?

Comment: I am not, I want to customize the entire style, change buttons, add classes to elements, delete header, add footer, etc.

Answer (score 2):

### First, please have a look at the documentation:

https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/datetime/DateTime/

#### Ionic DateTime components are looking like this one:

```
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Date</ion-label>
  <ion-datetime displayFormat="MM/DD/YYYY" [(ngModel)]="myDate"></ion-datetime>
</ion-item>
```

`[(ngModel)]` keeps track of a variable that can be set by yourself inside your controller. `displayFormat` is a comman formatting schema for your date. If you want to display for example in German format, then you will have to write `DD.MM.YYYY`.

#### For styling modifications check:

https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/datetime/DateTime/#sass-variables. There are five ariables for each device type (iOS, Android and deprecated Windows Phone):

- `$datetime-ios-padding-top`
- `$datetime-ios-padding-end`
- `$datetime-ios-padding-bottom`
- `$datetime-ios-padding-start`
- `$datetime-ios-placeholder-color`

#### For a working example look at the GitHub Page of Ionic:

https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-docs/blob/master/src/demos/api/datetime/index.html

Comment: Dead links :/ !!

Comment: @TheSegfault Thanks for the reply. I fixed the links.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's an old question, but if anyone still needs a method on customizing the look of the component here is my method.

I use Renderer2 from Angular to apply a part attribute to (in my case) calendar days so I can style them to my needs.

```
@ViewChild('calendar', { read: ElementRef, static: false }) calendar?: ElementRef;

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    timer(200).subscribe(() => { //async issues I couldn't resolve
        const shadow: DocumentFragment = this.calendar?.nativeElement.shadowRoot;
        const days = shadow.querySelectorAll('.calendar-day');

      days.forEach(day => {
            this.renderer.setAttribute(day, 'part', 'day');
        });
    });
}
```

Then I used regular scss to format.

```
ion-datetime {
  &::part(day) {
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 34px;
    height: 34px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this style in global.scss or your component style:

```
ion-datetime::part(calendar-day) {
    font-family: 'tahoma';
}
```